# What was the error? Should I have to use async await here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I am updating the user using mysql database after the update was successful I will call read function to return the users again but error occurring while the function was called. I am new to the nodejs.

**User read function**

```
    exports.read = (req, res) => {
      const userId = req.params.id;
      database
        .table('users')
        .withFields(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'user_role'])
        .filter({ id: userId })
        .get()
        .then(result => {
          console.log("result",result);
          if (result) {
            res.json(result)
          } else {
            return res.status(400).json({
              error: 'User not found'
            })
          }
        })
    }
```

**Update function**

```
    exports.update = (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.params)
      console.log(req.body)
      const updateuserId = req.params.id;
      const {name} = req.body;
      if (!updateuserId) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error : "Id required"
        })
      }
      if (!name || name =="") {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error : "Name is required"
        })
      }
      database.table('users')
        .filter({ id: updateuserId })
        .update({
          first_name: name
        })
        .then(updateStatus => {
          
          if (!updateStatus) {
            console.log("User update error");
            return res.status(400).json({
              error : "Update failed"
            })
          }else{
            const data={
              params:{}
            }
            **Calling read function**
            data.params.id = updateuserId;
            this.read(data);
          }
        })
       
    }
```

**Error**

```
    UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
        at D:folder_path:15:13`enter code here`
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    (node:163152) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:163152) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: I think you need to return something inside the .then(updateStatus). You only return on one side of the if

Comment: When you call `this.read()` inside of the `update()` function, the `read` function you show is expecting you to pass it `(req, res)`, but you're passing it `data`.  Then when the `read` function tries to use a `.json()` method, it won't be the right object.